# Henri Poincaré writings

Tags: soft-question, intuition, dynamical-systems, math-history

I have heard that Poincaré writings were very intuitive in its approach and not very formal in the arguments.
I'm searching for something like this to complement my study of dynamical systems.

I wonder if any of you has read any of Poincaré writings and can recommend those who are interesting for dynamical systems, three body problem, chaos...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wikipedia has links to several online versions of things by Poincaré:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9#Poincar.C3.A9.27s_writings_in_English_translation